# Result of 1+1 in odd digits number system

Tags: number-systems, even-and-odd-functions

Consider number system which uses only digits ${0,1,3,5,7,9}$ (odd digits with the except of 0). What will be the result in such system of summation `1+1` ? As I understand it should collapse into 1 or 3. What exactly it will be and why ?

**EDIT:**
As far as I understood - there is no canonical answer. Then question is - What are best / reasonable alternative definitions of `+` in such system. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can define the addition however you want. There may not be a canonical definition for a closed addition. Under normal addition, the system is NOT closed under addition.

Comment: @Agnius What kind of number system are you referring to? In order to answer questions about a mathematical object (like a number system) you should have a definition of it first.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Just edited the question. I'm not that good in math and can't think of _any_ alternative non-canonical definition.

Comment: The `number-systems` tag you used refers to representations with different radix bases, eg. binary vs. octal vs. decimal.  You ask about "odd digits with the except of $0$", but this doesn't specify what radix (if any) you have in mind.  With the six digits you *could* create a number system, but you have to define it before you can ask your Readers about it.  There is no ready-made system as far as I know.

Comment: @hardmath Base is 6 digits exactly these 0,1,3,5,7,9. Then you have a double problem - help me to create some primitive 6-based system :-) I'm not the good in math neither to create new number system, neither - new `+` definition in such system. I'm just interested in ways of describing `1+1=` at such number digits conditions

Comment: "Consider number system which uses only digits 0,1,3,5,7,9 (odd digits with the except of 0)"  You have to define what that *means*.  Now you can assume they are just symbols an paper and they can mean whatever you want but I assume somehow you mean $3$ is ... three... Well, you have to define how such a number system *works* before you do anything else.

Comment: What does $8 + 4$ mean in a system that doesn't have any symbols for values greater than $9$?  There is no symbol to represent it!  So we combine symbols as $12$ which is the number that equals $1\times 10 + 2$.  So $1+1 = 1+1$.  That's it.. that's as far as you can go.  I could invent a system where $x_1$ means the number $x + 1$ where $1 + 1 = 1_1$.  I can do whatever I want.

Comment: @fleablood I don't mean that it don't have any symbols greater that 9. it HAS - just number must be composed of 6 digits described. So 8+4 must be either 11 or 13

Comment: The point being you must manipulate *two* symbols to get the number we call "twelve".  So you must manipulate one or more symbols to get the number we call "two".  It's *your* number system.  Do whatever the #### you want.  Say $x + 1 = x_1$  Then we can have $1 + 1 = 1_1$ and $7_1 + 3_1 = 11_1$.  No biggee.  ... And no point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reasonable definition. Let's call the set $X = \{0,1,3,5,7,9\}$.

$\forall a,b\in (X\setminus \{0\})$, you have $a+b=0$ and $a+0=0+a=a$.

$0+0=0$

That makes sense. Odd numbers add together to the only even number. An odd number plus the only even number gives an odd number. This matches parity, but is not an easy addition to use. You do not even wind up with a basic mathematical structure like a group $(X,+)$. While you can create an addition that forms a group, it is unlikely to be "natural".

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in any addition definition, not only "natural" ones. To have some definition for `+` is better than NONE. As far as i understood reasonable definition is that summation of `1+1` results in `0`, yes ?

Comment: Correct, that is one possibility of many. The only reason why that might be a "natural" definition is because if you take your set (mod 2), the addition is the same. Otherwise, it is no better than any other definition for addition. None of them will really "mean" anything.

Answer (score 1):

What is a "number system"?  The Roman number system for example doesn't have any symbols for *any* of the numbers $2-4,6-9$ and yet has symbols of numbers Base 10 does not, such as $10, 50, 100, 500$ and $1000$.

So we can make up any system we want.   $a^b$ mean $a$ to the $b$ power and $ab$ means $a + b$.  Then the first several numbers can be written as

$0, 1,11,3,31,5,51,7,71,9,91,911,93,931,95,951,97,971,99,991,9911,993,9931,995,9951,997,9971,3^3,3^31, etc.$

Thing is ... this is a meaningless question.  I assume by number system you meant a radix systime where $abc = a\times k^2 + b*k+ c$ for some base $k$.  But that's impossible because that assumes you have $k-1$ symbols for each digit.  Having only odd digits simply wouldn't work at all.

ANd if we *don't* do radix we can do whatever we want.  Perhaps simplest would be to let $a' = a + 1$,  Then $1 + 1 = 1^1$ which is the number two.

Comment: Nice explanation about mapping between symbol and number